# How to install runtime extensions for DotNet 5

Tags: c#, .net-5, .net-runtime

I just installed DotNet 5.0, but I realized that I could not use any of the function from the runtime extensions. The program crashes every time I call any function from Random, Environement or Math, with the error `System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000064 from typeref (expected class 'System.Environment' in assembly 'System.Runtime.Version=5.0.0.0' ...)`.

I tried to install [this](http://%20https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Extensions/?fbclid=IwAR3DxrukdgTztmPZQ0BxsGBLlu9TNgbsEymU081nIKi8eFwx1dd2QmndsAA) by typing the command `dotnet add package System.Runtime.Extensions --version 4.3.1` but the program still crashes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, share the [mcve] and fix a dead link